# laravel post from view does not call controller method

Tags: laravel

I am trying to send a post request from my view but somehow this request is not passing to my controller method while other controller methods are working..

my routes:

```php
Route::get('/executes', 'ExecuteController@index')->name('execute.index');
Route::post('/executes', 'ExecuteController@store')->name('execute.store');
Route::get('/executes/create', 'ExecuteController@create')->name('execute.create');
```

my view:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-6">
                <h2>Create Execute</h2>
                <form method="post" action="/executes" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="pt-4">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                        @error('name')
                        <p class="pt-3 text-danger">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </p>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <label class="input-group-text" for="map">Map</label>
                        </div>
                        <select class="custom-select" id="map" name="map">
                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                            @foreach($maps as $map)
                                <option value="{{ $map->id }}">{{ $map->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        @error('map')
                        <p class="pt-3 text-danger">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </p>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

my controller:

```php
class ExecuteController extends Controller
{

  public function create()
    {
        return view('execute/create', ['maps' => Map::all()]);
    }

   public function store()
    {
        // is not even getting here
        dd('test');
    }

}
```

any ideas why my method is not getting called?

Comment: What method is being called instead or what is the error when you submit?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to change this

**FROM**

```
action="/executes"
```

**TO**

```
action="{{route('/executes')}}"
```

**OR**

```
action="{{url('/executes')}}"
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You're using named routes, so refer to their names when building a URL instead.

Example:

```
action={{url('execute.store')}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use {{ url('ROUTE_NAME')}} in action or where you want to give link

Answer (score 0):

guys thank you for your replies but the problem was on the frontend, I had a js included outside the html tag in my layout, somehow that messed up my store method, by fixing that it now works

Answer (score 0):

Use route in the form action as following

`action="{{route('execute.store')}}"`